# react-awesome-query-builder empty select when click outside select

Tags: reactjs, query-builder

I use asyncFetch and I select value from SelectWiget , after any click outside make empty value this select.

I use next config for fields

```
 products: {
      type: '!struct',
      label: 'Products',
      subfields: {
        title: {
          type: 'select',
          label: 'Name',
          fieldSettings: {
            asyncFetch: async (search, offset) => {
              const toSearch = _.isEmpty(search) ? 'null' :  search;
              const prodApi = (await axios.get(`http://localhost:8002/api/products/1/${toSearch}?offset=${offset}`, { headers: authHeader() }));
              const productsValues = prodApi.data.data.map(
                product => ({
                  title: product.title,
                  value: product.id
                })
              )

              return {
                values: productsValues,
                hasMore: true,
              }
            },
            useAsyncSearch: true,
            useLoadMore: true,
            forceAsyncSearch: false,
            allowCustomValues: false
          }
        },
```

Another error is when i select some value the asyncFetch is call again.

Is this a bug in that package or i have missing some configuration ?

the package what i use is  react-awesome-query-builder

Answer (score 0):

the value from result of function async need to be string, so function is like :

```
asyncFetch: async (search, offset) => {
          const toSearch = _.isEmpty(search) ? 'null' :  search;
          const prodApi = (await axios.get(`http://localhost:8002/api/products/1/${toSearch}?offset=${offset}`, { headers: authHeader() }));
          const productsValues = prodApi.data.data.map(
            product => ({
              title: product.title,
              value: product.id.toString(),
            })
          )

          return {
            values: productsValues,
            hasMore: true,
          }
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).